# Может ли команда "sudo reboot" привести к повреждению файловой системы (file-system corruption)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Может ли команда "sudo reboot" привести к повреждению файловой системы (file-system corruption)?

Comment: меня учили, что если есть подозрение в возможности повредить файловую систему, то лучше выполнить дважды sync.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если все компоненты в /etc/rc.d (init.d) работают корректно - то не должна. От самого reboot по сути ничего не зависит. Он дает сигнал процессу init. тот начинает выполнять скрипты завершения системы. В почти самом последнем скрипте завершения идет размонтирование файловых систем. В большинстве случаев оно проходит штатно и тогда повреждение файловой системы исключено. Но при неправильной настройке возможны ситуации при которых какие то файловые системы не могут размонтироваться и могут оказаться поврежденными после перезагрузке.

Comment: А почему `sudo reboot`? Перезагрузка же и без рута возможна?

Comment: @Qwertiy Обычно только руту. и лежит он обычно в /sbin, что как бы намекает и флага s даже в правах нет. С локальной консоли можно конечно Ctrl+Alt+Del нажать

Comment: @Qwertiy возможна `systemctl reboot` же.